# A user was receiving data from a subscribed report but now, the attached Excel reports are blank

Tags: reporting, subscriber, excel

A user is [subscribing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) to a report and is therefore, receiving automated emails with an Excel attachment of the subscribed report.

The report of a few hundred rows in a tabular format.

However, since the last two months, the attached report is blank.

When clicks on the report link from the email and logs into Salesforce to review the report, she can see all the data that she's expecting to see in that report.

The report has not changed nor has its running user. There are no long text fields in the report and no data is getting truncated.

It's unclear to me what the cause of this issue is and Salesforce Support has not currently been forthcoming.

**Question:**
Any ideas on why the aforementioned functionality *was* working fine but now, it isn't?

Comment: the attachment exists but has no rows?  or there is no attachment?

Comment: The attachment has no rows but there are many rows in the same report in Salesforce.

Comment: if you run the report as the running user (login as), do rows return?

Comment: I'm sure they do but will double check. I don't think it's to do with the running user / access level because the user sees the records once they've logged into Salesforce. 

It's odd that the data was displaying in the spreadsheet but now it isn't and only displays in Salesforce. The running user has not changed.

Comment: reports can run as a different user than the subscriber

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've opened a Salesforce Support case and will proceed with them. This remains a mystery (for now).